# Angular Validation Status of ngModelGroup

Tags: angular, angular-validation

I have one parent Angular Form that I wish to use in a number of sub components. To do this, I instruct my sub component to reuse the parent form:

```
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }]
```

Within my sub component, I have created a new ngModelGroup. The whole form shoudn't be valid until all the inputs are valid, but I would also like to know the validation of some of my child components.

Is there any method for determining the validation of my ngModelGroup?

Here is a stack blitz demoing my approach. I want to be able to check on the validation of the inputs within the sub.component.html's sub-form-group.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngform-bcj63c?file=app%2Fsub%2Fsub.component.html

Answer (score 1):

Within the Parent component, you can always access the FormGroup instance, which will include all the FormControls from Parent and Child components. This way you should be able to access the validation status of all the controls.

```ts
    // app.component.ts
    @ViewChild('userForm') ngForm: NgForm;

    someMethod() {
      const subFormGroup = this.ngForm.form.get('sub-form-group');
      if (subFormGroup) {
        console.log(subFormGroup.status);
      }  
    }
```

If this is not what you are looking for, and need a way for Child component to check/announce its validation status, please check below snippets and see if that helps.

- Display `ngModelGroup` status within Child component `html`

```html
    <!-- sub.component.html -->
    <div ngModelGroup="sub-form-group" #ngModelGroupRef="ngModelGroup">
      ...
    </div>
    <span>Status: {{ngModelGroupRef?.status}}</span>  <!-- ngModelGroupRef?.valid or ngModelGroupRef?.invalid -->
```

- The `ngModelGroup` can be accessed in Child component `ts` as:

```ts
    // sub.component.ts
    @ViewChild('ngModelGroupRef') ngModelGroup: NgModelGroup;

    someMethod() {
        console.log(this.ngModelGroup.status);
    }
```

- Accessing Child component `ngModelGroup` status in Parent component `ts`:

```ts
    // app.component.ts
    @ViewChild(SubComponent) sub: SubComponent;

    someMethod() {
      console.log(this.sub.ngModelGroup.status);
    }
```

- Another alternative to access Child component validation status in Parent component

```ts
    // sub.component.ts
    get validationStatus() {
      // Can include logic to calculate status for all the ngModelGroups within this component, in case if multiple present
      return this.ngModelGroup && this.ngModelGroup.status;
    }
    
    // app.component.ts
    someMethod() {
      console.log(this.sub.validationStatus);
    }
```

**PS:** The code sample in each step is build on previous step code, so for any step you may need to include the relevant code from previous steps too. Also do ensure that null/undefined checks are handled.